# How to specify derivative for SymPy custom function?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I am using sympy to help automate the process of finding equations of motion for some systems using the Euler Lagrange method. What would really make this easy is if I could define a function q and specify its time derivative qd --> d/dt(q) = qd. Likewise I'd like to specify d/dt(qd) = qdd. This is helpful because as part of the process of finding the equations of motion, I need to take derivatives (with respect to time, q, and qd) of expressions that are functions of q and qd. In the end I'll end up with an equation in terms of q, qd, and qdd and I'd like to be able to either print this neatly or use lambdify to convert this to a neat numpy function for use in a simulation.

Currently I've accomplished this is a very roundabout and annoying way by defining q as a function and qd as the derivative of that function:

```
q = sympy.Function('q', real=True)(t)
q_diff = diff(q,t)
```

This is fine for most of the process but then I end up with a messy expression filled with "Derivative (q, t)" and "Derivative (Derivative(q, t), t)" which is hard to wrangle into a neat printing format and difficult to turn into a numpy function using lambdify. My current solution is thus to use the subs function and replace q_diff and diff(q_diff, t) with sympy symbols qd and qdd respectively, which cleans things up and makes manipulating the expression much easier. This seems like a bad hack though and takes tons of time to do for more complicated equations with lots of state variables.

What I'd like is to define a function, q, with a specific value for the time derivative. I'd pass in that value when creating the function, and sympy could treat it like a generic Function object but would use whatever I'd given it for the time derivative instead of just saying "Derivative(q, t)". I'd like something like this:

```
qdd = sympy.symbols('qdd')
qd = my_func(name='qd', time_deriv=qdd)
q = my_func(name='q', time_deriv=qd)

diff(q, t)
>>> qd
diff(q**2, t)
>>> 2*q*qd
diff(diff(q**2, t))
>>> 2*q*qdd + 2*qd**2
expr = q*qd**2
expr.subs(q, 5)
>>> 5*qd**2
```

Something like that, where I could still use the subs command and lambdify command to substitute numeric values for q and qd, would be extremely helpful. I've been trying to do this but I don't understand enough of how the base sympy.Function class works to get this going. This is what I have right now:

```
class func(sp.Function):
    def __init__(self, name, deriv):
        self.deriv = deriv
        self.name = name

    def diff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.deriv

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        assert argindex == 1
        return self.deriv
```

This code so far does not really work, I don't know how to specify that specifically the time derivative of q is qd. Right now all derivatives of q are returning q?

I don't know if this is just a really bad solution, if I should be avoiding this issue entirely, or if there's already a clean way to solve this. Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: SymPy, dynamics...PyDy! https://www.pydy.org/

Comment: There s the `euler_equations` function for doing this. You could just substitute the derivatives for symbols at the end e.g. `eq.subs(q.diff().diff(), Symbol('qddot'))`. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/calculus/index.html#sympy.calculus.euler.euler_equations

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know about! If possible I would still like to find a way to control this more manually, if only for understanding and to make my skill at this more generalizable.